# Закрытые текущего окна в Delphi 7 и открытие следующего по нажатию кнопки

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Как при нажатии на кнопку (Log In), закрыть окно авторизации (Form1) и открыть основную программу (Form2)?

Код:

```
procedure TForm1.LogInButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  pw:string;
begin
  pw := 'NXJ';
  if PasswordEdit.Text = pw then
  begin
    Form1.Close;     {вот эта строка полностью закрывает программу}
    Form2.Show();
  end
  else
    ShowMessage('Wrong password');
end;
```

Comment: У вас точно Form2 является родительской формой? Судя по всему, нет, раз Form1.Close закрывает программу. Либо объясните тогда, ЧТО вы называете основной формой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Откройте Ваш .dpr файл (Project - View Source) и посмотрите порядок создания форм. Форма, которая создается первой с помощью `Application.CreateForm`, становится главной формой приложения. Ее закрытие ведет к выходу из программы.

Поменяйте местами строчки, создающие формы.

Comment: По умолчанию это может не решить проблему, мы же не знаем, как происходит вызов Form1

Answer (score 5):

Судя по всему, вы всё-таки основной формой называете не родительскую, а ту, в которой затем вы будете проводить основные действия. Тогда стоит сделать это по-другому:

```
<...>
begin
  Form1.Visible:=false;
  Form2.Show;
end
<...>
```

Что вы потом будете делать с `Form1` - уже на ваше усмотрение. Делайте это из методов `Form2`, но, в любом случае, вызов `Close` для родительской формы вызовет завершение программы.

Либо вам стоит пересмотреть подход и вызывать форму с логином из родительского окна, тогда затем можете смело ее закрывать.

Comment: Воспользовался первым способом, Благодарю!

Comment: А не подскажите ли, как безболезненно сделать Form2 основным?

Comment: @NickGrom Delphi 7 под рукой нет. В моей версии это делается очень просто: Project/Options, раздел Forms и просто выбираете, какая форма будет основной